# Can you merge two result sets into one from different tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server, union

I am trying to merge the results of two queries for an Authoriser into one result set for a grid.

SQL query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    Authoriser, ISNULL(TotalInvoices,0) AS TotalInvoices, 
    ISNULL(TotalRequsitions, 0) AS TotalRequsitions 
FROM 
    (SELECT
         Authoriser AS Authoriser, 
         COUNT(Tiffindex.Page_No) AS TotalInvoices, 
         null AS TotalRequsitions
     FROM  
         Tiffindex
     WHERE 
         Tiffindex.Doc_status = 7 
         AND authoriser != ''
     GROUP BY
         Authoriser
     UNION 
     SELECT
         Authoriser, null, 
         COUNT(RequisitionDetails.UploadTransaction_Id) AS TotalRequsitions 
     FROM
         RequisitionDetails
     WHERE
         RequisitionDetails.Doc_status = 7 AND authoriser != ''
     GROUP BY
         Authoriser) AS secondset
```

[image: Result Set with multiple rows per Authoriser]

Can the SQL be changed to merge the results into 1 Authoriser row?

The result I am getting can produce 2 lines per Authoriser. I'd prefer 1 if it is possible?

Thanks in advance,
Graham

Comment: no image please share text code

Comment: Wrap the union in a `GROUP BY` with `SUM` for the values

Answer (score 1):

YOu can try below -

```
SELECT Authoriser, sum(ISNULL(TotalInvoices,0)) AS TotalInvoices, sum(ISNULL(TotalRequsitions,0)) AS TotalRequsitions FROM (
    select Authoriser As Authoriser, Count(Tiffindex.Page_No) as TotalInvoices, null as TotalRequsitions
        from Tiffindex
        where Tiffindex.Doc_status = 7 and authoriser != ''
        group by Authoriser
    UNION 
    select Authoriser, null, Count(RequisitionDetails.UploadTransaction_Id) as TotalRequsitions 
        from RequisitionDetails
        where RequisitionDetails.Doc_status = 7 and authoriser != ''
        group by Authoriser
    ) as secondset group by Authoriser
```

Comment: Thanks fa06, that's also brilliant.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend aggregating by authoriser in the outer query, and then taking the sum of both other columns:

```
SELECT
    Authoriser,
    SUM(TotalInvoices) AS TotalInvoices,
    SUM(TotalRequsitions) AS TotalRequsitions
FROM
(
    SELECT
        Authoriser As Authoriser,
        COUNT(Page_No) AS TotalInvoices,
        NULL AS TotalRequsitions
    FROM Tiffindex
    WHERE Doc_status = 7 AND authoriser != ''
    GROUP BY Authoriser
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        Authoriser,
        NULL,
        COUNT(UploadTransaction_Id) AS TotalRequsitions 
    FROM RequisitionDetails
    WHERE Doc_status = 7 AND Authoriser != ''
    GROUP BY Authoriser
) AS secondset
GROUP BY
    Authoriser;
```